# find from array of patterns and run a method

Tags: java, regex

Hey I'm in a bit of trouble.

I need to check for about 200 regex patterns in a string, and according to the pattern found to run a method.

Meaning something like (semi-psuedo):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile([Array of patterns]);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {

 Pattern p = matcher.pattern();
 p.runSomeMethod();
}
```

Obviously, the above code is not the way to do it, just trying to clear what I need.

My problem is, to achive that I'd have to extend either `String` or `Pattern`, and the real problem is that they're both `final` so I can't do that.

Basically what I'm trying to do is look for multiple patterns in a string, when only 1 would fit, and run a procedure based on the pattern chosen, trying to avoid a huge switch case I though I'd just implement multiple classes that the pattern will return an object of my class and i'll just run it's method.

Any ideas how can I achive that? I found very little information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using the strategy pattern in combination with anonymous inner classes, like this:

```
private Map<Pattern, Runnable> patterns;
{
    {
        patterns = new LinkedHashMap<Pattern, Runnable>();
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("\\w+"), new Runnable() { public void run() { System.out.println("word");   } });
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("\\d+"), new Runnable() { public void run() { System.out.println("number"); } });
    }
}

public void matchAndExecute(String str) {

    Iterator<Entry<Pattern, Runnable>> it = patterns.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Pattern, Runnable> pattern = it.next();
        if (pattern.getKey().matcher(str).matches()) {
            pattern.getValue().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be really slow when going more then 200+ regex since they have to compile at run time? If I'd create all implementations as files and create a predefiner hashmap, I assume it will run faster. Is it possible?

Comment: Regexes always compile at run time. This method uses a class initializer so the regexes are compiled only once, during class initialiation. Any modern machine will compile 200 regexes in the microsecond range. You won't get it any faster than this unless you want to predict the best order in which to execute your regexes or by creating a smarter matching algorithm, both of which are exceedingly hard.

Comment: This seems to be the same as my idea. Although if the order of patterns is important, I would use a LinkedHashMap or a List of pairs.

Comment: @GáborBakos good suggestion. Dexter's idea and yours are both right. I just coded it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Map` for this, just create a class holding both Pattern and Runnable and fill a `List` (or an array) according to your needs.

```
class PatternMatcher {
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Runnable runnable;

    public PatternMatcher(PatternMatcher pattern, Runnable runnable) {
        this.pattern=pattern;
        this.runnable=runnable;
    }

    public boolean apply(String s) {
        if (pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {
            runnable.run();
            return true;}
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
PatternMatcher[] pm = {
    new PatternMatcher(...),
    new PatternMatcher(...),
    ...
};

for (PatternMatcher matcher: pm) {
    matcher.apply(s);
}
```

If you want to stop after the first matching pattern is found, use this loop:

```
for (PatternMatcher matcher: pm) {
    if (matcher.apply(s)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: corrected variable names

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a (LinkedHash)Map with keys for the Patterns and Runnable/Callable for the things to do? Would that work for you? That way you would visit the map and execute the value if the key matches/found.

Comment: Ya I thought about that, that would be my worst case scenrio option. The thing is the method I'd like to run is pretty complex and I'd like to arrange the code better then that, I'd really rather to find an "object-oriented" solution

Comment: I think the dynamic (OOP) languages use similar techniques for method calls, so not too different form object-oriented solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at `strategy` pattern.

You can implement an `interface` and based on the `pattern` matching you can call the appropriate method.

Usually to create the right instance without revealing the logic try 'Factory Pattern' though you will have to write your logic there

http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory

Comment: Yes but how would I know which pattern matched so I'd create the right instance?

Comment: @eric.itzhak may be factory pattern where you can encapsulate the logic for an instance?